# nsdate from picker to string and back to date, eventually passed to another controller

Tags: objective-c

uidate picker has proper user zone set.

```
NSDate *date= Uidatepicker.date;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle]; 
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimezone]];
//show correct date and time
NSString *string=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]; 

//back to date 
NSDate *outDate=[dateFormatter dateFromString:string];
```

The outdate is passed to another controller and eventually used to query db using time since 1970. The date used in the query has +4 hours (GMT time). I think it should have localtime. I know the NSdate has no timezone but I need the correct time for the db query. The db seems to have correct time since 1970 (based on local time). I am converting to string to check in this case as time is off by +4 hours.
Any suggestions and appreciate your help.

Comment: It's always good to standardize based on UTC or GMT all across both in your db while saving and in all your queries after getting the date from the user input. Take it all to either UTC or GMT.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am now storing in GMT and converting into local zone.